# Call dll multiple times error

Tags: dynamic, dll, hyperlink

I have a dll which I compile from files  CC.H

```
#ifndef CC_H
#define CC_H
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void __declspec(dllexport) ColorChange(float& r,float& g,float& b,float vel);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

and Fadeall.cpp

```
#include "CC.h"
void ColorChange(float &r,float &g,float &b,float vel)
{
r=0.9*r;
g=0.9*g;
b=0.9*b;
}
```

using commands
g++ -c Faseall.cpp -o CC.o
g++ -shared -o CC.dll CC.o -Wl,--out-implib, CC.a

I dynamically link dll using commands
myGLCanvas->CC_dll = LoadLibrary(L"CC.dll");
myGLCanvas->CCfn=(ColorChangeFn)GetProcAddress(myGLCanvas->CC_dll,"ColorChange");

Calling the function one time or even 100 times is ok, but calling this function 480000 times leads to an fault and program aborts.

```
for (int i=0;i<800*600;i++)
{
    myGLCanvas->CCfn(r,g,b,0.8);
}
```

Comment: I simplified the code to int ColorChange(int r,int g) {return r+g;} same behaviour

Comment: The problem was in Function definition in main function: was typedef void (__stdcall *ColorChangeFn) (float&,float&,float&,float); needed typedef void (*ColorChangeFn) (float&,float&,float&,float);, suppose by definition it is __cdecl

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions